# Undentified Publisher on a signed setup executable during install with Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, signing, publisher

I have a setup executable which I have signed with a Verisign cert. The executable displays the correct publisher information during installation with XP and Win7, but on Vista it displays it as "Unidentified Publisher". I've checked each and every individual file that gets put into the msi and the executable manually using the Properties menu to verify that those files are signed, and they are indeed signed with a signer and timestamp BUT not an email. (Is there a tool that does this?).

If I run the msi contained inside the executable, and cancel the installation before it is complete. Then when I run the SAME setup executable that was complaining about Unidentified Publisher again, it displays the correct publisher information.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I may solve this problem? I am aware of the bug with windows installer on Vista for uninstalls, but this is an install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tool are you using to sign the package, is is SignTool.exe? If so, are you getting the certificate from a path specified on your machine or you've specified for SingTool.exe to get it from the store.

The recommended method is to import the certificate in the store and then ask for SignTool to use it from there.

This problem appeared for me only if the SignTool.exe used was from Windows SDK v.7.0 or later.

Comment: Yes, it is SignTool.exe. The certificate is also stored on the machine.

The problem seems to be fixed now! Thank you!!